# Android SIGSEGV in libskia

Tags: android, bitmap, segmentation-fault

Currently I'm writing an app that  decode a lot of bitmap from file periodically (to play a png sequence as 30 fps). So every 41ms I need to decode a bitmap. The problem comes as the app crash ramdomly with SIGSEGV. The trace provided by ndk-stack is like below:

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/fortunave3gxx/fortunave3g:5.0.2/LRX22G/G530HXCU1BPE5:user/release-keys'
pid: 8624, tid: 9332, name: pool-1-thread-1
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x48
Stack frame #00 pc 0008f686  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN15AndroidPixelRefC1ERS_RK11SkImageInfojP12SkColorTable+17)
Stack frame #01 pc 0008cecd  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
Stack frame #02 pc 000b2d7b  /system/lib/libskia.so (_ZN8SkBitmap11allocPixelsEPNS_9AllocatorEP12SkColorTable+34)
Stack frame #03 pc 001403f5  /system/lib/libskia.so (_ZN17SkPNGImageDecoder8onDecodeEP8SkStreamP8SkBitmapN14SkImageDecoder4ModeE+244)
Stack frame #04 pc 0013d72d  /system/lib/libskia.so (_ZN14SkImageDecoder6decodeEP8SkStreamP8SkBitmap11SkColorTypeNS_4ModeE+38)
Stack frame #05 pc 0008d6e5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
Stack frame #06 pc 0008df49  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
Stack frame #07 pc 01247ed3  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
```

To schedule the file decode I use ScheduledThreadpoolExecutor:

```
 public void scheduleSequenceDraw() {
    if (!timerScheduled) {
        Log.d("SEQUENCE", "Called sequence schedule");
        timerScheduled = true;

        if (numFrames > 1) {
            futureCancel = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (isPausing) return;
                    updateCurrentFrame(currentFrameNum);
                    synchronized (numFrameLock) {
                        currentFrameNum = (currentFrameNum + 1) % numFrames;
                    }
                }
            }, 0, (long) (1000.0 / fps), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } else {
            // if there's only 1 frame, we don't need to SCHEDULE a timer
            updateCurrentFrame(currentFrameNum);
        }
    }
}
```

I searched around and frustrated as I can't figure out what cause this bug. All the drawing is written in Java with no native code. Any suggestion on how to trace the crash or a better method for recurring decode Bitmap is highly appreciated.

Comment: I have same problem... If you discover plz, post the fix